# android while loop alternative

Tags: android, while-loop

This is my first Android application and I am finding troubles with while loop, I am trying to use a while loop on my Android application but the application freezes.

What I'm trying to do is track the user location (using onlocationChanged) and keep querying on the location until the query returns a result. It's a GIS application so I am going to describe the application behavior:
the application keeps tracking the user position using a listener "onLocationChangedListener" and store it in a variable "myPosition". I am using a boolean"noResults=true". I will use a method "query(myPosition)" in the while loop, this method has a callback that when a result is found, and changes a boolean "noResults" to false.  the loop will keep on until "noResults" is false (that means query's callback changed the boolean's value)

, here's what I did:

```
while(noResults)
{
//myPosition keeps changing 
      query(myPosition);
//query has a callback that when a result is found it changes noResults to false
}
```

Comment: share you code here.

Comment: Please post your code here, and be remember always to share code when your question is regarding technical things.

Comment: try to get the location in a secondary thread, not on the main thread

Comment: Where did you put your "while"? If it;s in onCreate you're blocking the main thread!!!

Comment: please check the edits

Comment: Why do you need the while loop? I don't understand. The current position is passed by the onLocationChanged method. Please explain your problem and post more code. Where is the while loop? In main? In onLocationChanged? In onCreate?

Comment: the while loop is in main. It's my first android application,  I am using while loop because I dont know any other alternatives. Is there any alternative to while loop? I've found some suggestions like "handler" but I am having problems with the syntax and understanding how it works.

Comment: actually it was the key, just wanted to post the specific response. Thanks by the way ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

running while loop codes on the main thread freezes the UI, and makes all other processes pause making your app unresponsive use

```
Threads..
```

also note that the while loop you are running is running on a default Thread termed as the ui thread so in short run while loops on separate threads..
eg..

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
    // Your hard while loop here
    //get whatever you want and update your ui with ui communication methods.
    }
).start();
```

for ui communicating methods

```
View.post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "updated ui", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

the view could be any views you are updating.. 
also like @TehCoder said you could use asynctask but asynctask is not meant for long workaflow work there are 3 of them but i can't recall the last one

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem using a "Handler" that query the Feature Layer every 5 seconds, this stops the main thread from generating application not responding error:

```
   Handler m_handler=new Handler();
    Runnable m_runnable;
    m_runnable = new Runnable(){
   public void run() {

  //query code here
m_handler.postDelayed(m_runnable, 5000);

    }
   };
  m_handler.postDelayed(m_runnable, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use an AsyncTask? I'm not quite sure what your problem is tho.

Comment: The problem is it is a long workaflow work and I read that AsyncTask should be used for brief workaflows

Answer (score 0):

Loop is not a problem in android (or any language).

There are two scenario might be reason for your freezing,

1. If you run network call in api, android throw error and crashes. You have to do network related calls in Aysnc Task ot threading
2. Use try throw catch and exception cases to avoid app crashing and better coding skill.