# Why is my app in Android Studio freezing when I press a button?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, freeze

I had made an app (in Android studio 3.0.1) that tells whether the number which was entered is a triangular number, or a square number, or both, or none. However, when I enter a number and press the "enter" button, the app just freezes, and stops responding. I tried changing the type of loops (for/while)...but it did not yield any result.

I have given below the .java code...

```
package com.example.home.numbershape;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {




    class testNumber {
        int n;
        int i = 0;
        int tTestnum;
        int sTestNum;
        boolean triangular;
        boolean square;

        boolean triangleTest(){
            while( tTestnum <= n){
                int tTestnum = i*(i+1)/2;

                if( n == tTestnum){
                    triangular = true;
                } else if(n > tTestnum){
                    i++;
                } else {
                    triangular = false;
                }

            }
            return triangular;
        }

        boolean squareTest(){

            while( sTestNum <= n){
                int sTestNum = i*i;

                if( n == sTestNum ){
                    square = true;
                } else if(n > sTestNum){
                    i++;
                } else {
                    square = false;
                }
            }
            return square;



        }


    }





    public void submitFunction(View view){

        testNumber num = new testNumber();

        EditText inNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputNum);
        String nString = inNum.getText().toString();
        num.n = Integer.parseInt(nString);


        if(num.triangleTest()){
            if(num.squareTest()){
                Toast.makeText(this, "It is both a triangular and a square number!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "It is a triangular number.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } else if(num.squareTest()){
            if(num.triangleTest()){
                Toast.makeText(this, "It is both a triangular and a square number!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "It is a square number.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
         else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "It is neither.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        Log.i("Info", "Submitted and checked.");



    }





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}
```

Here is the .xml code a well...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.home.numbershape.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputNum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="84dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="85dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="enter the number."
        android:inputType="number"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:singleLine="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/submitButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="292dp"
        android:layout_height="113dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="33dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="46dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:text="This app tells you whether the number which you have typed in is a Square number, triangular number, both or none. So give it a go!"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/inputNum"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submitButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="221dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="148dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="148dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:onClick="submitFunction"
        android:text="enter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputNum" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Did I make any mistakes in the code structure? Please do tell what's wrong...
Thank you!

P.S: Here is the log `05-24 10:35:45.471 2322-2322/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/ActivityThread: Service com.google.android.gms.autofill.service.AutofillService has leaked IntentReceiver com.google.android.gms.autofill.smsretriever.TracingSmsBroadcastReceiver@88dcee that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
                                                                                 android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Service com.google.android.gms.autofill.service.AutofillService has leaked IntentReceiver com.google.android.gms.autofill.smsretriever.TracingSmsBroadcastReceiver@88dcee that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
                                                                                     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1588)
                                                                                     at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1368)
                                                                                     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1515)
                                                                                     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1488)
                                                                                     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1476)
                                                                                     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:627)
                                                                                     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:627)
                                                                                     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:627)
                                                                                     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:627)
                                                                                     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:627)
                                                                                     at lkl.<init>(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):5)
                                                                                     at ljc.<init>(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):1)
                                                                                     at kxb.a(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):10)
                                                                                     at bzlo.a(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):5)
                                                                                     at kxj.a(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):2)
                                                                                     at bzlo.a(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):5)
                                                                                     at kvm.b(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):0)
                                                                                     at lfu.onFillRequest(:com.google.android.gms@200414022@20.04.14 (040700-294335909):70)
                                                                                     at android.service.autofill.-$$Lambda$I0gCKFrBTO70VZfSZTq2fj-wyG8.accept(Unknown Source:8)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl.doInvoke(PooledLambdaImpl.java:300)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl.invoke(PooledLambdaImpl.java:195)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.OmniFunction.run(OmniFunction.java:86)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
05-24 10:35:59.300 2114-2146/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module`

Comment: Could you post the log?

Comment: You are using while loop in triangleTest ... that might be the reason I recommend you to check this...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54264125/android-studio-while-loop-freezing-application

Comment: @PraveenSP, I am new to Android studio...so can you please explain what "put into a service" means in the post you have referenced? It might be a silly question, but still...

Comment: Check this also once... [While-Loop-Alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26378529/android-while-loop-alternative)

Comment: @GabrielAbraham only the error i.e. the text in red when your app freezes ...or is there none?

Comment: @AdityaKurkure, I have updated the log.

Answer (score -1):

You have not referenced your button in your Java code. Try Adding this code in the `onCreate` method of your `Main` Activity

```
Button Sbutton = findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
```

Comment: The function mentioned inside xml onClick attribute of button so no referencing required again in java file